# Angular custom filter logs out as working with some matches but filters out all results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I think I may have a syntax error in here somewhere. The idea is that the user selects currencies that they are interested in. Subsequently I only want to print out rows of the currencies table that have a matching currency. I am using a custom filter to achieve this.

I want to either fix my custom filter syntax or look at a way to use a built in filter to achieve the same thing.

```
//directive html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Gram Price</th>
      <th>Ounce Price</th>
      <th>Kilo Price</th>
      <th>24 hr Change</th>
      <th>1 yr Change</th>
      <th>10 yr Change</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="quote in vm.quotes | selectedCurrencies:vm.selectedCurrencies()">
        <th scope="row">{{quote.currency}}</th>     
        <td>{{quote.price}}</td>
        <td>{{quote.ouncePrice}}</td>
        <td>{{quote.kiloPrice}}</td>
        <td>{{quote.change.d1}}</td>
        <td>{{quote.change.y1}}</td>
        <td>{{quote.change.y10}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

//filter
angular.module('bgAngularTest').filter('selectedCurrencies', function($log) {
    return function(quotes, selectedCurrencies) {
        if(!quotes.length){
            return;
        }
        return quotes.filter(function(quote) {
            selectedCurrencies.forEach(function(cur){

                $log.info(quote.currency +' ==== '+ cur + ' ?');

                if(cur === quote.currency){
                    $log.info('match');
                    return true;
                }
            })
            return false;               
        });
    };
});

//example of quote data

{
    "quotes": [{
        "currency": "USD",
        "price": 40.55,
        "symbol": "$",
        "change": {
            "d1": 0.0116,
            "y1": 0.0425,
            "y10": 1.1029
        }
    }, ...]
}

//example of currency list

["RUB","USD","EUR"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selectedCurrencies.forEach` doesn't actually return anything, because the callback is internal to the `forEach`:

```
if(cur === quote.currency){
    $log.info('match');
    return true;
}
```

You return `false` all the time, and all your items are filtered out. Try this instead:

```
return quotes.filter(function(quote) {
    return selectedCurrencies.some(function(cur){ // if at least one currency matches return true
        return cur === quote.currency;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes that works. I had just noticed that I was always going to be returning false as well. Nice use of .some().